# Aptana studio 3 installation error

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I've just installed Aptana Studio 3 on windows.  I have installed ruby 192 with rubyinstaller.  When I try to execute a code I get:

c:\Ruby192\bin\rubyw.EXE: No such file or directory -- Studio (LoadError).

What should I do now?

Thanks,

Comment: I am receiving the same error. Where can we find more detailed error stack to post?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with debugging on Windows in Studio 3.0.3, see http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3075

This is fixed in the upcoming 3.0.4 release. You can grab the bugfix by changing to the beta or nightly update streams: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Changing+the+Update+Type

Answer (score 0):

From inside Aptana Studio, choose the following menu options:

Window >> Preferences >> expand "Install/Update" >> Available Software Sites >> checkbox either Beta Updates OR Nightly updates >> click OK

then:

Help >> Check for Updates

I chose Beta Updates, then chose Check for Updates, Aptana then installed the latest Beta Release.