# Error Dealing with Rails in Aptana

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, aptana, aptana3

I have installed:
-Aptana studio v 3.0.9
-Ruby 192p290
-DevKit
-Git

And I was creating rails project using aptana and run the `rails s` command from its terminal; everything worked fine till yesterday.
I tried to do the same but I got an error when dealing with any rails commands like:

rails new .
or
gem -v

Error is:

```
$ rails new .
C:\Ruby192\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- /cygdrive/c/Ruby192/bin/rails (LoadError)
$ rails -v
C:\Ruby192\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- /cygdrive/c/Ruby192/bin/rails (LoadError)
$ gem -v
C:\Ruby192\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- /cygdrive/c/Ruby192/bin/gem (LoadError)
```

I don't know what going on, I googled the problem and followed every instruction that could help me, but the same problem still exists.
Also I uninstalled Aptana, Ruby, DevKit and Git and reinstalled them again.

Note that the everything works fine outside Aptana so nothing wrong with the environment variables pathes, the error in Aptana itself. Also I use the instructions [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850556/aptana-studio-3-installation-error)

My system is
Windows Vista

The only new thing that I did since the last time aptana was working with rails that I installed virtualbox to run ubuntu inside windows.

Any Ideas to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it by making alias for gem, ruby & rails. I found the ans [here](http://www.question-defense.com/2009/03/27/rubyexe-no-such-file-or-directory-cygdrivecrubybingem-loaderror).
So All what I wrote the following commands in the terminal of Aptana:

```
alias ruby='C:/ruby192/bin/ruby.exe'
alias rails='C:/ruby192/bin/rails'
alias gem='C:/ruby192/bin/gem'
```

And it works fine now, running rails from inside aptana terminal on a windows machine.